# How to django update related fields?

Tags: django

How to updtae data to related field.

```
 User.objects.filter(id=int(getupdate['uid'])).update(cnf_user__User_Code=getupdate['code'])
```

It's not work.

This is Model.

```
class Cnf_User(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    User_Code = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='-')
    User_Tel = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='-')
    User_Status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    User_Level = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='-')
```

Comment: replace  **filter** with  **get**

Comment: This below answer it's work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
Cnf_User.objects.filter(user_id=int(getupdate['uid'])).update(....)
```

btw, `Cnf_User` is not proper name for class in python :P Better would be `CnfUser` or even full meaning of "Cnf" maybe `ConfigUser` :P?

Same with fields:

```
User_Code -> user_code
```

Comment: Sorry, It's not error. But It's not commit in to database

Comment: What You mean saying "it's not commit to database"? :)